# StringComparison to keep the Directory.GetFiles sort in C# .NET Core

Tags: c#, linux, .net-core

I have a program, written with `net471` and uses [`Directory.GetFiles`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles?view=netframework-4.7.1).

Now we want to convert it to *.NET Core* and run it on *Linux*.
When we do this, we get a different order of files.

I know what the docs say:

> The order of the returned file names is not guaranteed

But until we moved to Linux, files were fixed order.

We want to keep this order, **do we need to write a comparer ourselves**, or does one already exist?

Rules:

- *Underscore* after without: `file.txt -> file_en.txt`.
- *Name with number* after without: `file.txt -> file1.txt`
- *Number* before *Underscore*: `file1.txt -> file_en.txt`
- *Alphabetical numbers*: `10.txt -> 3.txt`
- *Ignore case*: `AA.txt -> ab.txt -> ZZ.txt`

If there is a comparer for that, we need it to be an OS agnostic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [How to compare strings in C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/how-to/compare-strings#code-try-1) (and the *Try.NET*) you need to use [`OrdinalIgnoreCase`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringcomparison#System_StringComparison_OrdinalIgnoreCase) to get these rules.

For example:

```cs
var files = Directory.GetFiles(folderName);
Array.Sort(files, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

Comment: Doesn't work for numerical comparisons, e.g. `10.txt -> 3.txt` (as per OPs requirement)

Comment: @MatthewWatson - it does work, because OP wants numbers to be sorted alphabetically. And with `OrdinalIgnoreCase` the `string` `"10"` is "less than" `"3"`.

Comment: Ah I was reading `10.txt -> 3.txt` as  meaning that `10` should follow `3` (I was reading the `>` as "greater than").

Comment: @Matthew Watson What do you recommend me to write instead of `->`

Comment: @baruchiro It's fine as you wrote it really - I just didn't parse it properly :)  I suppose you could say that you require `"10.txt" < "3.txt"` (using `<` as  "less than"), but it's not really necessary.

Answer (score 4):

The order of the files isnt guaranteed in .net framework either (from the .net framework docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles?view=netframework-4.7.1):

> The order of the returned file names is not guaranteed; use the Sort method if a specific sort order is required.

Your application's behaviour should be no better or worse than it is now. As the docs suggest, you can use `Sort` to guarantee the order of the files. `Sort` takes an implementation of `IComparer` so you can implement the rules above if you really need to ensure that things are returned in this order.